# trying to install mcrypt. brew getting in way

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt

ok. so i've been trying to install mcrypt to use in laravel for the last few days and I know it should not be taking this long, so I am coming to you guys for help. I followed this tutorial exactly:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/

but when I try to brew doctor, I get errors saying:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.la
```

how do i get homebrew to recognize mcrypt as something I want on my computer? please let me know which files you would like me to post.